# Separar números de una cadena de texto en php

Tags: php, php7

Amigo necesito poder separar los numeros de una cadena de texto para asi poder aplicar un estilo diferente a estos por ejemplo el usuario entraria la cadena de texto `20 de julio de 1995` la idea es que el resultado final sea que el 20 y el 1995 tenga un estilo diferente al que tiene el texto, para esto tendria que separar el texto de los números, ¿como podria hacer eso?

Comment: Probaste con expresiones regulares? Personalmente para trabajar fechas siempre me descargo el paquete Carbon.

Comment: No he probado con expresiones regulares, como seria la implementacion en este caso?? pues el texto que puse es un ejemplo, no necesariamente son fechas con las que se tiene qu trabajar

Comment: @JhonnyLuis por favor edita y muestra que has intentado al momento

Comment: Hasta el momento no he intentado nada, estoy apena en busca de opciones y recomendaciones

Comment: échale un ojo a `Carbon` https://packagist.org/packages/nesbot/carbon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como te comentaron, puedes usar expresiones regulares para extraer los números.

**¿Qué es una expresión regular?** ([Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_regular))

> Es una secuencia de caracteres que conforma un patrón de búsqueda.

**Extracción de números**

El siguiente código es un ejemplo de una extracción numérica simple de un texto.

```
$re = '/(\d{1,})/';
$str = '20 de julio de 1995';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

Este sería el resultado de `var_dump($matches);`

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "20"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "20"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "1995"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "1995"
  }
}
```

La función `preg_match_all` busca en todo el string por coincidencias que concuerden con el patrón (expresión regular) que almacena `$re`. Los resultados que se capturan con los paréntesis de captura `(...)`, y dentro se específica lo que se quiere guardar en la variable `$matches`, en una cantidad de uno a infinito `{1,}`. En este caso buscamos dígitos con `\d`.

Luego la expresión regular se enciera entre barras slash `/REGEX/`. Al final de la expresión regular se pueden entregar modificadores que indican ciertos comportamientos como:

- `m`: buscar en un string multilínea
- `i`: insencibilidad a mayúsculas y minúsculas
- `x`: ignorar espacios en blanco

En el ejemplo le indicamos que busque si el string es multilínea, es decir, si el string tiene los carácteres de línea nueva `\n`.

**Guías**

Las expresiones regulares pueden ser muy complejas y tortuosas si nunca las has usado. Te dejo unas guías para que te capacites al respecto.

- [Expresiones Regulares en PHP – La Guía definitiva](https://maugelves.com/expresiones-regulares-en-php/)
- [PHP-TUT-13 Expresiones regulares](https://eldesvandejose.com/2016/05/27/expresiones-regulares/)
- [PHP Doc: Sintaxis de expresiones regulares de PCRE - Introducción](https://www.php.net/manual/es/regexp.introduction.php)
- [Rápido y completo: Expresiones Regulares en PHP](https://www.igdonline.com/blog/rapido-y-completo-expresiones-regulares-en-php/)

**Testeo online**

También puedes armar la expresión regular con una herramienta online como [regex101](https://regex101.com/) o [phpliveregex](https://www.phpliveregex.com/).

Comment: Los paréntesis y el modificador `/m` son innecesarios. Sería lo mismo que `/\d+/`

Comment: Ya lo he quidato. Gracias